# Moving an id at mediaquery in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie in JS. I'm trying to move a photo from one div to another  @mediaquery with JS. It is moving nevertheless but is not coming back when am changing the dimension of the browser at more then 767px. Probably my thinking is bad at else statement, but I don't know how to do it!
if I delete the else completely is not working anymore...

any help is highly appreciated it! Thank you!

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
    document.getElementById("img_move").append(document.getElementById("img_dest"));

  } else{
    document.getElementById("img_dest").append(document.getElementById("img_move"));
  }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("max-width: 767px")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

Answer (score 0):

It couldn't be the exact answer of the question but it's other resolution. Without deleting but it's just making other id's img element. And then hiding original one on the other hand showing other id's img element. Both have same image but displaying is different on condition.

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) { // If media query matches    
    document.getElementById("img_dest").style.display = 'none'    
    document.getElementById("img_dest2").style.display = 'block'

  } else{
    document.getElementById("img_dest").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("img_dest2").style.display = 'none'
  }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

```html
<div id='img_move'> dd</div>
<div id='img_dest'> over 767px</div>
<div id='img_dest2'> under 767px</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several errors which mean that it never reaches the myFunction on a media state change. I have put them in comments here. A good place to look to understand JS functions and methods is MDN, this link gives basic info. on sensing media state changes: `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener`

Once those are mended you will see in your browser's console log that your attempt at moving an image fails as you alter the viewport width. I am not at all clear what you actually want to do here - swap the src in the two img elements perhaps?

```
<script>
function myFunction(event) {  //on a state change you get myFunction called but with parameter event, not x
  if (event.matches) { // If media query matches
    console.log('media query matches');
    document.getElementById("img_move").append(document.getElementById("img_dest"));
// you will see an error here: on Firefox: media query matches test14.html:11:13
//HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy
//on Edge 
//Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'append' on 'Element': The new child element contains the parent.
//    at MediaQueryList.myFunction (file:///C:/Users/annet/Documents/test14.html:1

  } else{
    console.log('media query does not match');
    document.getElementById("img_dest").append(document.getElementById("img_move"));
  }
}
var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)");//brackets were missing so never saw media width changing

//myFunction(x); // Call listener function at run time - this function needs an event to match up the media tests with

x.addListener(myFunction); // Attach listener function on state changes

</script>
```

Comment: Thx for the response Haworth. I'm just trying to send one img from a div to another at break point. Nothing more, from one div to the other and vice versa.